# Website not loading on Safari iOS after font added

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I added a new font to my wordpress website. The font is rendering correctly and the site is loading properly in chrome and firefox on both desktop and mobile. It is loading on desktop safari as well, however on safari iOS the site will not load. it just sort of gets stuck in the loading state with the horizontal blue bar as the top a quarter of the way. If I remove the font then then problem goes away. Has anybody run into this type of issue? I have not been able to find any solutions on the web.

I've been following the suggestions in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-web-fonts-getting/)

And [this article](https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/kb/troubleshoot-adding-fonts-website.html) says I need to specify the font-weight, but even when I've done so the issue persists

Here is my code:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Boston Light';  
    src: url('custom-styles/fonts/Boston-Light.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Boston Regular';
    src: url('custom-styles/fonts/Boston-Regular.woff') format('woff'); 
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Boston SemiBold';  
    src: url('custom-styles/fonts/Boston-SemiBold.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Boston Bold';  
    src: url('custom-styles/fonts/Boston-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}
body, button, input, select, textarea, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, .tagcloud a {
    font-family: 'Boston Regular', 'Open Sans', Georgia, sans-serif;
}
.menu-main-navigation-container a,
.menu-main-navigation-container a:hover,
.menu-main-navigation-container a:focus {/*nav items*/
    color: #744364;
    font-family: 'Boston Light', Montserrat, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use woff2 format of these fonts.

I found an example of Boston Regular [here](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/cc46c2b9439ea730c16a6a07533f4933).

Comment: wow, this seems to have solved it! I updated to .woff2 formatted and it did the trick. it is weird though, because according to caniuse.com .woff should work just fine in iOS safari: https://caniuse.com/#search=woff

Comment: Nice to know that! Sometimes minor changes may solve greater problems. Actually, there are lots of things that are not supported by iOS Safari, including some CSS properties and image formats.

Answer (score 1):

I have no deeper insides on this, but I once had a similar problem.
I changed the path by adding a `/` before the folder and it helped. You might want to give it a try.

Try adding a `/` in the beginning to all urls like this:

```
src: url('/custom-styles/fonts/Boston-Light.woff') format('woff');
```

Comment: Thanks, when I read this suggestion I thought for sure it would work. unfortunately when I applied it did not correct my use case

Comment: This did the trick for me! It even works with relative paths.